# Override POST in CreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my django app I have two models i.e. `Package` and `Address`

Models.py

```
class Package(models.Model):

    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    sender_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sender_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    sender_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    sender_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    sender_country = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='India')


class Address(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='India')
```

I am overriding the `post` method in my `CreateAPIView` like the following:

```
class package(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post (self, request, format=None):

        ...

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("s data", serializer.data)

            Address.objects.create(user=request.user.id, name=request.data["name"],
                                  city = request.data["city"]...)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is there any other way to save Address from package model when a `Package` object is created ??

Comment: check out https://www.dabapps.com/blog/django-models-and-encapsulation/

Comment: I think Django signals is the best practice to do this.

Comment: You can override `save()` of model `Package` to create an `Address` object.

Comment: @Tarique Can you show me how or provide an example ?

Comment: @RahulSharma: does the answer satisfy you? if yes then please mark as accepted and close the question. Or ask further queries. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can override `save()` of model `Package` to create an `Address` object:

Here is code snippet:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # save Package
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            address = Address(user=..., name=...)
            address.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

this is just an example. You probably want to validate inside `save` that if address already exists or not. It all depends on your application logic.
check out this for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

hope this helps.